# Can iNotify tell me where a monitored file is moved?

Tags: linux, inotify

I want to monitor a file while it's moving in the system. Can iNotify tell me its new position whenever it's moves?

Answer (score 3):

If you're watching both the directory the file was moved from, and the directory the file was moved to, then you will receive an `IN_MOVED_FROM` event on the source directory and an `IN_MOVED_TO` event on the target directory, both with the same `cookie`. You can then use the `name` fields of the two events to find out where the file was moved to and from.

If you're only watching the source directory, or only the target directory, then you will only get one of the events, so you will only have half of the info. This is a limitation of inotify.

Comment: How about monitor the file with "IN_MOVE_SELF"? I don't know where a file will be moved, so I need to know the new file path when it's moved.

Comment: No, like I said, you won't get any information about the move destination unless you're watching the directory it moved to.

Answer (score 3):

You can grab a file descriptor to the file before the move and read the symlink at:

```
'/proc/self/fd/' + $fd
```

where $fd is your file descriptor, this file descriptor will point to your file. Note I have only tested this on ext4 and it works with LVM2, but does not work with OverlayFS. Also opening a file descriptor will block remove events from being fired for the file.

There may also be issues between linux kernel versions

Comment: its not much clear how it can be used.

Comment: Background:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_(system_call)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Creating a file handle to the file before the move operation will allow you to track it's new location by reading the symlink at:
`'/proc/self/fd/' + $fd`

Most programming languages have a way to open a file. When a file is open by a process it creates a file descriptor which is usually represented by a unique number issued by the operating system; that is the $fd variable in question.

Comment: I'd used auditctl and it worked (but required sudo).

Answer (score 0):

According to @slightly_toasted's answer [there](https://serverfault.com/a/1073564/923518), you can use `sudo auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,rmdir,unlink,unlinkat,renameat -F dir=/path/to/folder/to/monitor -F key=DONT_MOVE`.

The `DONT_MOVE` key/tag is what identifies the file/folder you'll be monitoring.

You can create different tags to different files/folder you are going to watch.

To ensure that these rules are stored, append the same command (except `auditctl`) `-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,rmdir,unlink,unlinkat,renameat -F dir=/path/to/folder/to/monitor -F key=DONT_MOVE` to the `/etc/audit/audit.rules` file.

For this, you can use: `sudo echo "-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,rmdir,unlink,unlinkat,renameat -F dir=/path/to/folder/to/monitor -F key=DONT_MOVE" >> /etc/audit/audit.rules` (it says permission denied so it need a fix)

---

## Then

The file/folder is missing and you want to know its new path? Use `ausearch -k DONT_MOVE` (`DONT_MOVE` or any other tag you chose individually for every file/folder you wanted to monitor)